# Symfony 2 FosUserBundle connect user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have an old application that i coded in pure php without use some Framework.

And i buildt very Simple User System to connect to the webSite.

In my V2 I'm beginning to use Symfony2 Framework and it s great.

But when the user connect to the Website, he have to cross my first application, with my old system, and when he use the new module that i code in Symfony i want to connect him with FosUserBundle to this part of the Website.

My question is: How Can i connect him in the Symfony Application in the controller without use some template, just using the Controller.

Thanks.

I just want to tell that i have a variable with the name of the User if he's connection in the first part of the webSite.

Comment: I do not understand this part: "How Can i connect him in the Symfony Application in the controller without use some template, just using the Controller.".

But from here: "I just want to tell that i have a variable with the name of the User if he's connection in the first part of the webSite." I would say use `sessions`.

Comment: Thats mean : If the user log in the first part to log him automaticlly without forms, just in the controller

Comment: Than you should set sessions in the first part of the app, then in second part of the app in controller read session, authenticate with fosuserbundle and redirect to where ever you want to.

Comment: Good, my question is HOw authenticate with fosuserbundle , what i have to do.

Answer (score 2):

The code should go something like this:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

public function authenticateAction()
{

     // ... fetch user data preferably from session
     // find user using Entity Manager and store user object into $user variable


    // Here, "public" is the name of the firewall in your security.yml
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "public", $user->getRoles());
    $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

    // Fire the login event
    // Logging the user in above the way we do it doesn't do this automatically
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
    // maybe destroy session and redirect out here

}
```